# Trying to create HTML live filter table in WordPress with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am have made an example table on my WordPress site.

```
`<input id="search" class="text" type="text" placeholder="type text" ><table><tbody><tr>
<td>George</td>
<td>Washington</td>
<td>Virginia</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>Benjamin</td>
<td>Franklin</td>
<td>Philadelphia</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>Thomas</td>
<td>Jefferson</td>
<td>Virginia</td>
</tr></tbody></table>`
```

However, I am trying to make a live filter search of this table using jQuery on this specific page with post id 2977. I have added the wp_enqueue function to the bottom of my functions.php code in WordPress.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts' );
function custom_scripts() {
    if (is_page(2977)){
        wp_enqueue_script('custom_scripts', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/custom_scripts.js', array('jquery'));
}
}
```

The custom_scripts.js file looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// Write on keyup event of keyword input element
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        _this = this;
    // Show only matching TR, hide rest of them
        $.each($("#table tbody tr"), function() {
            if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1)
               $(this).hide();
            else
               $(this).show();                
        });
    }); 
});
```

jQuery code from http://jsfiddle.net/9hGym/293/

I have tried this code repeatedly, but the table never filters itself. If someone can point out where I am going wrong and why, that would be great.

Comment: `#table` in your selector is the problem use `table tbody tr` instead. `#` denotes an id. So your other option is to give te table an id of "table"

Comment: the demo works for me....problem is not clear

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.